# how to handle a RestResponse

Tags: rest, grails

I have a RestResponse resp which looks as a text like this:

```
resp.text = [{"class":"org.strotmann.bic.BankIdentCode","id":1,"bankname":"Sparkasse Aachen","bic":"AACSDE33XXX","blz":39050000,"ort":"Aachen","plz":52059},{"class":"org.strotmann.bic.BankIdentCode","id":2,"bankname":"Aareal Bank","bic":"AARBDE5W100","blz":10010424,"ort":"Berlin","plz":10666},{"class":"org.strotmann.bic.BankIdentCode","id":3,"bankname":"Aareal Bank Zw L","bic":"AARBDE5W108","blz":51010800,"ort":"Wiesbaden","plz":65011},{"class":"org.strotmann.bic.BankIdentCode","id":4,.........]
```

I want to access its components

```
"id":1,"bankname":"Sparkasse ....
"id":2,"bankname":"Aareal
```

and each component with a `getAt("bankname")` to obtain its value

which methods can I use ?

peter
Dortmund, germany

Comment: what is your ultimate problem here?  are you having problems parsing the json or do you want to build some map to store the result?

Comment: If you are using rest client builder, then use `resp.json` instead of `resp.text` after which you can do `resp.json.collect { it.bankName }` to get all bank names (for example).

Comment: This is not a REST response, because it does not contain links. The client should not know anything about URI structures, they should get links with URIs or URI templates...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` for this.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(textResponse);
```

And use `array.getJSONObject(index)` to get `JSONObject` and `array.length()` to get the number of elements.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(0);
String bankname = jsonObject.getString(bankname);
int id = jsonObject.getInt(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Grails/Groovy**, you can use this following :

```
def resp = grails.converters.JSON.parse(response)
```

Then,  access by *resp.id, resp.bankname*